# Create and update multiple series in Zingchart

Tags: javascript, zingchart

I'm trying to graph some Network data in Realtime using Zingchart. I'm using websockets to send data from a twisted pyton server to Zingchart. 
Is there any way to identify which serie to update? For instance if a have this serie:

```
 'series': [
    {
      'text': 'Serie 1',
      'values': []
    },
    {
      'text': 'Series 2',
      'values': []
    }
  ]
```

use "text" or another id to identify the serie to update with the data sent via websockets? Also is it possible to create series dynamically from the websocket?

Answer (score 0):

Well, It might not be a right solution for you.

you can just write code below;

```
zingchart.exec('myChart', 'appendseriesvalues', {
  plotindex : 0,
  values : [[time,newValue-20]]
});

zingchart.exec('myChart', 'appendseriesvalues', {
  plotindex : 1,
  values : [[time,newValue+10]]
});
```

The point is you can set right order of the plotindex attribute;

I modified script source from [the site](https://www.zingchart.com/gallery/chart/#!time-series-line-chart) below, see how it works.

Here is a complete source;

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    zingchart.MODULESDIR = "https://cdn.zingchart.com/modules/";
    ZC.LICENSE = ["569d52cefae586f634c54f86dc99e6a9", "ee6b7db5b51705a13dc2339db3edaf6d"];
  </script>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .zc-ref {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='myChart'><a class="zc-ref" href="https://www.zingchart.com/">Charts by ZingChart</a></div>
  <script>
    var myConfig = {
      gui: {
        contextMenu: {
          position: 'right',
          docked: true,
          alpha: 0.9,
          item: {
            textAlpha: 1
          },
          button: {
            visible: true
          }
        }
      },
      graphset: [{
        type: 'line',
        borderColor: "#cccccc",
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 2,
        plot: {
          aspect: 'spline'
        },
        plotarea: {
          margin: 'dynamic'
        },
        utc: true,
        timezone: 9,
        title: {
          text: 'Uniform Step Time Series Line Chart',
          adjustLayout: true,
          align: 'left',
          marginLeft: '15%'
        },
        legend: {
          draggable: true,
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          header: {
            text: "Facility N",
            backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0'
          },
          marker: {
            visible: false
          },
          //item: {
          //  margin: '5 17 2 0',
          //  padding: '3 3 3 3',
          //  fontColor: '#fff',
          //  cursor: 'hand'
          //},
          verticalAlign: 'middle',
          borderWidth: 0
        },
        scaleX: {
          //minValue: 1484870400000, //set minValue timestamp
          //minValue: 1512018819470,
          //step: 'day', //set step for scale
          step: '30minute',
          //step: 'minute',
          maxItems: 7,
          itemsOverlap: true,
          zooming: true,
          transform: {
            type: 'date',
            all: "%d %M %Y<br>%g:%i:%s"
          }
        },
        preview: {
          adjustLayout: true,
          live: true
        },
        scaleY: {
          step: 50,
          label: {
            text: 'Sensor'
          },
          guide: {
            lineStyle: 'solid'
          }
        },
        crosshairX: {
          lineColor: '#555',
          plotLabel: {
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            multiple: true,
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderRadius: 2,
          },
          marker: {
            size: 5,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#fff'
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          visible: false
        },
        series: [{
          values: [],
          text: 'Sensor FC-456',
          legendItem: {
            backgroundColor: '#29A2CC',
            borderRadius: 2
          }
        }, {
          values: [],
          text: 'Sensor AB-265',
          legendItem: {
            backgroundColor: '#D31E1E',
            borderRadius: 2
          }
        }, {
          values: [],
          text: 'Sensor DC-445',
          legendItem: {
            backgroundColor: '#7CA82B',
            borderRadius: 2
          }
        }, {
          values: [],
          text: 'Sensor ER-985',
          legendItem: {
            backgroundColor: '#EF8535',
            borderRadius: 2
          }
        }]
      }]
    };

    zingchart.render({
      id: 'myChart',
      data: myConfig,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    });

    //Set up of a websocket
    var ws = new WebSocket('ws://65.50.232.201:8888/', 'zingchart');
    //var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/examples/websocket/chartProgrammatic');
    //var ws = new WebSocket('ws://192.9.112.69:8080/examples/websocket/sychart');


    //Tell our internal server what to send.
    ws.onopen = function(){
        //console.log("########send##########");

        ws.send('zingchart.feed');
        ws.send('zingchart.push');
        ws.send('zingchart.getdata');
    }

    //Setup an event to call a ZingChart API Method to update our chart.
    ws.onmessage = function (e) {
        console.log("===== \n " + JSON.stringify(e.data));
        console.log("===== \n ");

        //var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        var newValue = data['plot0'][1];
        var time = data['plot0'][0];

        //console.log("====> " + time);
        //console.log("====> " + newValue);

      zingchart.exec('myChart', 'appendseriesvalues', {
          plotindex : 0,
          values : [[time,newValue-20]]
      });

      zingchart.exec('myChart', 'appendseriesvalues', {
          plotindex : 1,
          values : [[time,newValue+10]]
      });

      zingchart.exec('myChart', 'appendseriesvalues', {
          plotindex : 2,
          values : [[time,newValue+150]]
      });

      zingchart.exec('myChart', 'appendseriesvalues', {
          plotindex : 3,
          values : [[time,newValue+200]]
      });

    };

    ws.onclose = function(event) { 
        console.log('Client notified socket has closed',event); 
    }; 


  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The output is as follows;

[image]

I hope it will help you.